# MVC2 - Controller class is not serving correct JSP page after valid request parameters are passed to it

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller, javabeans

This is my first MVC application.  I have a Controller.java file, 3 JSP files, and one JavaBean.  In my controller, I have a conditional expression that sends the user to a invalid date page when they enter a date < or = todays date.  The problem is, when the user hits the back button on the browser, and enters a valid date, the only page that continues to get served from my controller is the invalid date page.  What am I doing wrong?  I tried searching online for a answer but was unable to find a similar problem (or at least I personally could not find one).

Here is my Controller.java file:

```
public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
public static final String BOOKING="booking";
/** 
* Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code> methods.
* @param request servlet request
* @param response servlet response
 * @throws javax.servlet.ServletException
 * @throws java.io.IOException
*/
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    ServletContext servletContext = getServletContext();
    String address;
    String hikeName = request.getParameter("hikeName");
    String duration = request.getParameter("dur");
    String hikeDate = request.getParameter("hikeDate");

    Booking b = (Booking) session.getAttribute(BOOKING);
    if (b == null) {
        b = new Booking();
        session.setAttribute(BOOKING, b);
        address = "/bookingView.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = servletContext.getRequestDispatcher(address);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);  
    }
    else {
        if (b.dateCompare(hikeDate)) {              
            b.calculateCost(duration, hikeDate);
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher;
            dispatcher = servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/quoteView.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } else {
            session.getAttribute(BOOKING);
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher1 = servletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
            dispatcher1.forward(request, response);

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my JavaBean:

```
public class Booking {
private String hikeName;
private String begDate;
private String endDate;
private String dur;
private int baseRate = 60;
private int duration = 0;
private int cost = 0;
private double premiumRate = baseRate * 1.5;
private DateTime jbegDate = new DateTime();
private DateTime jendDate = new DateTime();
private Boolean success = true;
private DateTime today = new DateTime();
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/YYYY");
private LocalDate myDate = new LocalDate();
private LocalDate myDate2 = new LocalDate();

public void setHikeName(String hikeName) {
    this.hikeName = hikeName;
}
public String getHikeName() {
    return hikeName;
}
public void setBaseRate(int baseRate){
    this.baseRate = baseRate;
}
public int getBaseRate(){
    return baseRate;
}
public void setPremiumRate(int premiumRate){
    this.premiumRate = premiumRate;
}
public double getPremiumRate(){
    return premiumRate;
}
public void setDur(String dur){
    this.dur = dur;       
}
public String getDur(){
    return dur;
}
public void setBegDate(String begDate){
    this.begDate = begDate;
}
public String getBegDate(){
    return begDate;
}
public void setEndDate(String dur, String begDate){
    duration = Integer.parseInt(dur);
    this.begDate = begDate;
    DateTime dateOfHike = f.parseDateTime(begDate);
    jendDate = dateOfHike.plusDays(duration - 1);
    endDate = jendDate.toString(f);  
    this.endDate = endDate;
}
public String getEndDate(){
    return endDate;
}
public Boolean dateCompare(String begDate){
    myDate = f.parseLocalDate(begDate);
    if (myDate.isBefore(myDate2) || myDate.isEqual(myDate2))
        success = false;
return success;
}
public Boolean getSuccess(){
    return success;
}
public int getCost() {
    return cost;
}
public int calculateCost(String dur, String begDate){
   duration = Integer.parseInt(dur);
   this.begDate = begDate;
   DateTime dateOfHike = f.parseDateTime(begDate);  
   jendDate = dateOfHike.plusDays(duration - 1);
   int premiumDays = 0;
   int normalDays = 0;

   while (dateOfHike.isBefore(jendDate)) {
        int dayOfWeek = dateOfHike.getDayOfWeek();
        if (dayOfWeek == 6 || dayOfWeek == 7) {
            premiumDays++;
        } else {
            normalDays++;
        }
        dateOfHike = dateOfHike.plusDays(1);
    }
    if (jendDate.getDayOfWeek() == 6 || jendDate.getDayOfWeek() == 7) {
        premiumDays++;
    } else {
        normalDays++;
    }
    cost = (int) (normalDays * baseRate + premiumDays * premiumRate);
    return cost;
}
```

}

In the JSP form page (bookingView.jsp), I simply collect 3 parameters using a text field and two drop downs.  I use a GET method here.

In the quoteView.jsp page, I present the user with a table that has the 3 parameters along with 
a calculated end date and a calculated trip cost.  This is where the controller is supposed to send the user assuming they entered valid data in the form.

If they didn't enter a valid date then they see the index.jsp form that just tells them to go back and enter a valid date.  This is where the code gets stuck (meaning that once it goes to this page, it stays at this page regardless of whether the user enters valid data or not).  On each subsequent request, I can see that the data I am selecting in the form is being passed upon SUBMIT in the address bar using the HTTP GET.  But my controller is not using the request parameters to update my view...

Comment: If you do not show the jsps, should should say for each if it contains a form, and if the form has method get or post and in a few words what id shows.

Comment: How and where do you update your bean ? How do you call the method `processRequest` ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I understand what was going wrong.  The value of my `setSuccess()` method was not being updated after the else code block.  By resetting its value back to TRUE right before end of the else code block, it allowed the controller to enter to evaluate the if `(b.dateCompare(hikeDate))` each time a new request was sent to the server from the browser.  Hope it may help some other noob out in the future.